# Best way to replace sentences/paragraphs with a string in python

Tags: python, text, nlp, text-processing, text-parsing

How would I replace all the sentences and paragraphs with a `<string>` tag in text files?

I want to keep spacing, tabs, and lists in the text document intact:

Example input:

```
Clause 1:

  a) detail 1. some more about detail 1. Here is more information about this paragraph right here. There is more information that we think sometimes.

  b) detail 2. some more about detail 2. and some more..
```

Example output:

```
<string>

  a) <string>

  b) <string>
```

Comment: Can you give an example from the data in the file?

Comment: @OferSadan Some examples here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uenclomviw082q0/1.txt?dl=0, https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmym96x68sqgow8/2.txt?dl=0, https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3jb6s8xjfrelna/3.txt?dl=0

Comment: In text such as `1. Confidentiality Undertaking – ...`, do you consider the `1.` as part of the paragraph, or part of "everything else"?

Comment: Also, pretty much every sentence and paragraph will contain punctuation, spacing, tabs, etc., so it's unclear how to keep those things intact while also replacing the sentence/paragraph with a tag. You should probably give a small example of input and desired output.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDyck, you are quite right, I didn't completely think this through. The bullets and lists should be left alone, but I suppose punctuation will need to be removed as well? Here is an example input & output:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/uenclomviw082q0/1.txt?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/w18y21b5pd7jj1a/1-labeled.txt?dl=0

Comment: I've been looking at this thinking it might be able to help with what I need: https://spacy.io/universe/?id=spacy-sentence-segmenter

Comment: @echan00: You should give a small example of input and output explicitly in the problem statement, not via links in a comment. And I don't think a sentence segmenter will help you at all.

Comment: good idea! i just updated the post itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the *best* way, but it's fairly straightforward, and easy to modify. It handles the example in your problem statement, plus most of the example from your comment.

```
import sys, re

text = sys.stdin.read()

# A pattern expressing the parts of the input that we want to preserve:
keeper_pattern = r'''(?x)  # verbose format

    (   # We put parens around the whole pattern
        # (and use ?: for subgroups)
        # so that when we use it as the splitter-pattern for re.split(),
        # the result contains one string for each occurrence of the pattern
        # (in addition to the usual between-splitter strings).

                    # The main thing we want to keep is paragraph-separators,
                    # and the 'lead' of the line that follows a para-sep:
                    #
        \n{2,}      # two or more newlines, followed by
        \x20*       # optional indentation (zero or more spaces), followed by
        (?:         # an optional item-marker, which is
          (?:         #   either
            \d+ \.    #       digits followed by a dot,
            |         #   or
            [a-z] \)  #       a letter followed by a right-paren,
          )           #   followed by
          \x20+       #   one or more spaces.
        )?

        |
                    # The other thing we want to keep is
                    # item-markers within paragraphs:
                    #
        \( i+ \)    # a lower-case Roman numeral between parens
                    # (generalize as necessary)
    )
'''

for (i, chunk) in enumerate(re.split(keeper_pattern, text)):

    # In the result of re.split(),
    # the splitters (keepers) will be in the odd positions.
    is_keeper = (i % 2 == 1)

    if is_keeper:
        if chunk.startswith('\n'):
            # paragraph-separator etc
            replacement = chunk
        else:
            # within-para item-marker
            replacement = ' ' + chunk + ' '
    else:
        if chunk == '':
            # (happens if two keepers are adjacent)
            replacement = ''
        else:
            # everything else
            replacement = '<string>'

    sys.stdout.write(replacement)
```

Comment: thanks, this is what i'm looking for, it doesn't take care of all the cases, but I'm going to add more to see if it is possible to resolve all of them

Comment: actually, i'm finding that my output is returning multiple <string> tags for a paragraph of sentences even though I only want one tag to represent all of them. How would I go about changing this? I've updated the input/output to be a little more clear

Comment: When I run the above code on your revised example input, I get your example output, so the behavior you're describing must be due to a change you made to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use **re** module:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,     to replace!\n to replace?\n\thelll34234ooooo'
>>> re.sub(r'(\w+)', '<string>', text)
```

It outputs:

```
>>> '<string>,     <string> <string>!\n <string> <string>?\n\t<string>'
```

**re.sub** means: replace every occurrence of `(\w+)` in `text` with `<string>`.

For file:

main.py:

```
import re

with open('main.py', 'r') as input:
    text = input.read()
    print(text, '\n\n----------------\n')
    print(re.sub(r'(\w+)', '<string>', text))
```

output:

```
import re

with open('main.py', 'r') as input:
    text = input.read()
    print(text, '\n\n----------------\n')
    print(re.sub(r'(\w+)', '<string>', text)) 

----------------

<string> <string>

<string> <string>('<string>.<string>', '<string>') <string> <string>:
    <string> = <string>.<string>()
    <string>(<string>, '\<string>\<string>----------------\<string>')
    <string>(<string>.<string>(<string>'(\<string>+)', '<<string>>', 
<string>))
```

Comment: Thanks @Persi but I'm hoping to replace the entire sentence or paragraph with <string>, not each word